# Incluir DLL en ejecutable

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Quería saber si era posible incluir las dll en el ejecutable de forma tal que me quede todo incluido en un solo archivo ejecutable en Visual Studio 2012 con C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De forma estándar no se puede lograr lo que estás planteando.

Si podrías analizar, si.
Quizás creando una **`Aplicación Portable`** que permite encapsular tu aplicación junto al framework de .net, aunque no es algo simple de lograr".

Podría analizar el uso de las Herramientas

- [VMware ThinApp](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_ThinApp)
- [ThinApp](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp.html)

Comment: Quería importar otras librerías, como la de SQLITE, gracias por la respuesta, lo voy a revisar

Answer (score 2):

El **framework** en si no lo puedes incluir completo, pero si puedes tus DLL, y DLL de terceros usando [ILMerge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17630)

### Ejemplo de uso:

- [Fusionando los ensamblados .NET usando ILMerge](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9364/Merging-NET-assemblies-using-ILMerge)

Answer (score 0):

Pues mira puedes incluir tus dll en referencias y ademas agregarlos en Resources, luego puedes copiar esas dll si no existen en la misma carpeta de tu archivo ejecutable al iniciar tu aplicativo, de esta manera al ejecutar tu aplicativo copiara esas dll que les falta :

Por ejemplo de esta manera :

pathname: directorio raiz, 
resourcename  : nombre de tu dll

```
Dim b() As Byte = My.Resources.resourcename  
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pathname,b)
```